# Client Certificate code doesn't work when installed on Web Server - works in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl-certificate

I have used the following code in two different ASP.NET MVC websites.  When I run the code on my client workstation using Visual Studio 2013, the X509Certificate2Collection "certificatesInUserStore" successfully returns all of the current user's client certificates.  This occurs successfully in IE and Firefox.

However, when I deploy the applications to the web server, no personal certificates are received.  I deployed one web site (no DB backend) using the DefaultAppPool with passthrough and the second web site with an application pool using a service account for identity.  The web server is IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 and is configured as follows:

1. Bindings are https with a fully qualified hostname and a self signed SSL cert (I have added the self signed cert to the trusted CA authority list on the  client workstation web browser).
2. Anonymous, ASP.NET Impersonation, Basic, Form, and Windows authentication are all disabled.
3. SSL is "Require SSL" and "Require Client Certificates".
4. iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentiation is enabled with manyToOneCertificateMappingEnabled and a mapping to a local server account with permissions to the website directory structure.\

I'm hopeful that someone can help me get to the bottom of my configuration problem.  Thanks in advance.

```
public static X509Certificate2Collection GetClientCertificate()
{
    x509Store UserStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    try
    {
        UserStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInUserStore = UserStore.Certificates;
        int certCount = certificatesInUserStore.Count;
        if (certCount == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("No client certificates present.");
        }
        return certificatesInUserStore;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("An error occurred attempting to retrieve client certificate");
    }
    finally
    {
        UserStore.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, there are no certificates on the web server.

Comment: There is a self-signed certificate on the web server.  This certificate is selected in the HTTPS bindings for both web sites and is found in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

Comment: With the code above, it hits the IF condition and displays the "No client certificates present." exception.  When you comment out the IF condition, no exceptions / errors are encountered, but I've written code that will display all retrieved certificates to the UserProfile page.  When running in debug mode, I see the certificate details.  When running on the server, I see nothing.

Comment: For clarity, debug mode is on a client workstation with Visual Studio 2013 and IIS Express....selecting either IE or Firefox.  Nothing was done special with the IIS Express configuration.

Comment: The certificate isn't installed in the `CurrentUser\'My` on the server. Looks like it is installed in a different store.